# Force Outlook to reply on a declined ICS-File with a Reply ICS-File

Tags: email, outlook, calendar, icalendar

My ICS file looks like this:

```
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:spatie/icalendar-generator
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20211002T080000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20210930T142933Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:218eb275-5e35-4e9a-a4c2-b9ea7ed91e34
DTSTAMP:20220627T142933Z
SUMMARY:Appointment
DESCRIPTION:Description
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
ORGANIZER;CN=organizer:MAILTO:organizer@mail.com
ATTENDEE;CN=attendee;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:attendee@mail.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20220629T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20220629T170000
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:FREE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I decline this appointment in a google workspace after I received it via email, I get a reply email with an ICS-File attached, which has the `REQUEST: REPLY` method. However, when I decline this appointment in outlook, I do get an reply email to the organizer email, but there is no ICS file attached.

I need this ICS-file in the reply email, because its contains necessary information. Is there a way to force Outlook to attach the file to the email?